# Does anyone know of certain galaxies that are at certain distances from Earth?

Tags: space, map-making, distance

Okay, I have this quadrumvirate of godlike aliens, each born far from Earth. I would like to make a map of the universe for their fictional homeworlds that use existing galaxies. I’ll refer to the beings as Alien A, B, C, and D, and their respective homeworlds as Planet W, X, Y, and Z. And here’s the statistics:

- Alien A is 772724 Earth years old, and was born on Planet W, which is about 12.2 billion lightyears from Earth;
- Alien B is 680411 Earth years old, and was born on Planet X, which is about 10.7 billion lightyears from Earth;
- Alien C is 494913 Earth years old, and was born on Planet Y, which is about 7.8 billion lightyears from Earth;
- And Alien D is 240373 Earth years old, and was born on Planet Z, which is about 3.8 billion lightyears from Earth.

Anyways, I’m asking if anybody knows of any galaxies that are of the given distances from Earth, as any attempt to look them up has been unhelpful. The distances don’t have to be exact, you just have to provide at least one galaxy per range, that has a distance from Earth that rounds to the given values.

Comment: There are literally billions of galaxies within the distances you're talking about, and only a scant few have individual names. In general, it is more helpful to look up galaxy clusters and superclusters at these scales, because these can be studied all at once and thus might actually have entries in cosmology papers. It'll also help your search to convert those distances to redshifts, which are used more often in the literature; assuming they're comoving distances, you should be looking at roughly z=1.2, z=1.0, z=0.7, and z=0.3.

Comment: @parasoup Thanks. That’s really helpful.

Comment: @parasoup However, according to the calculator I found, the redshift values are off by being lower somewhat.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so Planet W could be SPT0418-47, which is about 12 billion light-years away.
https://earthsky.org/space/alma-distant-milky-way-lookalike-galaxy-spt0418-47

Planet X could be the cluster galaxy IDCS J1426.
https://www.republicworld.com/technology-news/science/nasa-shares-picture-of-most-massive-galaxy-cluster-located-10-billion-light-years-away.html

Planet Y could be in El Gordo, a galaxy cluster about 7 billion light-years away. https://chandra.harvard.edu/photo/chronological12.html

Planet Z could be PS1-10jh , which is about 2.7 billion light-years from Earth. https://chandra.harvard.edu/photo/2012/ps1/

Planet Z could also be Abell 1758, which is a galaxy cluster about 3 billion light-years away. MACS J1149 is about 5 billion light-years.
This Cluster: RX J1532, is about 3.9 billion light-years away.

There are far more named galaxies that are a lot closer than the billions of light-years you have named though. There are some in the thousand and millions. I'm not sure if you're interested in a closer range, but here are some resources for them if you are interested. https://chandra.harvard.edu/photo/chronological12.html

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_nearest_galaxies

Also a note:
Galaxy Cluster: It is a large group of galaxies bound together with gravity. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galaxy_cluster

Comment: While it’s helpful, the galaxies are a good amount closer to Earth than I’m asking for. For example, PS1-10jh is 1.1 billion lightyears closer than Planet Z’s specified distance.

Comment: Okay, you did say they didn't have to be exact, but I found a few galaxy clusters farther here:https://chandra.harvard.edu/photo/2014/rxj1532/ and put in an edit. Accuracy is difficult at this distance though because the distances you ask for are incredibly extreme.

Comment: Thanks. It should be around that distance.